# how can I access the array response using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to android development.

I am trying to access the response array object properties using a simple `for` loop in kotlin. Shipping is an `array` that compose from a function inside mu `viewModel`

```
RESPONSE: [Data1(trackingId=588015573030500172, _id=64d1a52c20ba414c150467b2, price=100.0)]

 if (shipping?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
    for (ship in shipping!!) {
        Log.d("HELLO", ship.toString())// I want to be able to do ship._id
     }
 }

ViewModel

 val shipping = searchTackingId
        .debounce(400L)
        .onEach { _isSearching.update { true } }
        .combine(_shipping) { text, shipping ->
            if(text.isBlank()) {
                shipping
            } else {
                delay(400L)
                getShipping(text)
            }
        }
        .onEach { _isSearching.update { false } }
        .stateIn(
            viewModelScope,
            SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
            _shipping.value
        )


private suspend fun getShipping(trackingId: String): List<ShippingByTrackingIdQuery.Data1?>?{
    val response = apolloClient().query(ShippingByTrackingIdQuery(trackingId = trackingId)).execute()
    if (response.hasErrors()) {
        Log.w("ShippingByTrackingId", "Failed to login: ${response.errors?.get(0)?.message}")
    }
    val result = response.data?.shippingByTrackingId?.data

    if (result == null) {
        Log.w("ShippingByTrackingId", "Failed")
    }

    return result
}
```

Comment: What type is Shipping? How are you converting the response to a class? Or have you not done that yet?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I updated the question to be more specific. Thanks for your interest in advance

Comment: You say it’s an array. An array of what? Your question is asking how to get a certain property from the class of items in the array. The way to do that depends on what class that is and how you created it. You have a function returning an `Array<Any>>` which is something I’ve never seen in sensible object-oriented code.

Comment: You’re apparently using some library for converting a string response into some kind of class. From that class you’re getting something called `shippingByTrackingId`. Need to understand how you defined that to understand how to solve your problem.

Comment: Plz provide your dataClass as well.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I come from typescript that may explain why I may missed use the Any property. I edit my question. Please look at val shipping to see the conversion response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, you should correct the return type of your function because now it is `List<Any>` therefore your objects will be cast to `Any` then you can't access to its properties.

So change `Any` to the correct type which i guess it is `Data1` in this case:

```kotlin
private suspend fun getShipping(trackingId: String): List<Data1?>? {
    ...
}
```

Comment: edited my question. The above does not work for me

Comment: @JoseCC do you collect data from shipping in your activity/compose? another question is what is the result of `Log.d("HELLO", ship.toString())` it is very helpful